# How to give position relative to particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want `.ra` to be `position:relative` to the `.da`.

When i give `position:relative` to `.ra` div it moves according to the parent `div`.

What can be the `CSS` please help me.

```
<div>
<div class="ra">hi</div>
<div></div>
</div>

<div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<div style="float:left;"></div>
<div class="da">....</div>
</div>
```

```css
.ra
{
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
    top:450px;
    min-width:101px;
    min-height:256px;
}
.da
{
    float: left;
    width: 287px;   
    padding: 0 5px 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way `.ra` could be relative to `.da` would be if `.ra` were positioned *inside* of `.da` - which is not the case. You need to modify your HTML accordingly.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="da">
    <div class="ra">
        This is relative to parent
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.da{
    position: relative;
}
```